# How do I correctly pass the files changed in one stage into another pipeline stage

Tags: encryption, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Apologies in advance as I'm not very confident writing GitLab pipelines. I have a pair of public and private keys encrypted, committed to the GitLab repo. I have introduced a new stage into my pipeline in order to decrypt the keys and deploy.

```
decryption:
  stage: decryption

  allow_failure: false

  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  script:
    - chmod 660 ./keys/vault_password.txt
    - echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD > ./keys/vault_password.txt
    - chmod 660 ./keys/private.key
    - chmod 660 ./keys/public.key
    - ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ./keys/vault_password.txt ./keys/private.key
    - ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ./keys/vault_password.txt ./keys/public.key
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/private.key)"
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/public.key)"

  artifacts:
    untracked: true
```

My next stage is `build`.

```
build:
  stage: build

  allow_failure: false

  dependencies:
    - decryption

  script:
    - rm -rf vendor/drupal/coder
    - composer install
    - ./vendor/bin/robo ci:build
    - ls -la vendor/drupal/coder
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/private.key)"
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/public.key)"

  artifacts:
    name: "mycompany_build_{$CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    expire_in: '1 week'
    paths:
      - ./build
```

When I try to echo the keys in the `decryption` stage I can see the **decrypted** keys. But, when I try to access the keys like this in the `build` stage like below, it shows me the **encrypted** files. I'm just trying to see if I can access the decrypted files at the `build` stage and then I can pass these keys to be deployed. So clearly something is not correct with the pipeline.

```
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/private.key)"
    - echo "$(cat ./keys/public.key)"
```

Maybe the way I have written my pipeline needs to be changed in order to pass the changed untracked public.key and private.key into the build stage and possibly to the `deploy` stage as well.

Could someone please point me in the correct direction on this?. Do I have to change something in the artifacts ?. How can I do that?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about GitLab-ci but I think you are not referencing properly the decrypted file, on the decrypting step you should save the decrypted value to a variable and then call it on the build step, the way you are doing now is referencing the file itself in the build step the file is not decrypted, you decrypt on the decrypt step and save the decrypted value to use late.
I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe you can get the idea:
Decrypt:

````yaml
decryption:
  stage: decryption

  allow_failure: false

  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  script:
    - chmod 660 ./keys/vault_password.txt
    - echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD > ./keys/vault_password.txt
    - chmod 660 ./keys/private.key
    - chmod 660 ./keys/public.key
    - ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ./keys/vault_password.txt ./keys/private.key
    - ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file ./keys/vault_password.txt ./keys/public.key
    - echo "private_key_value=$(cat ./keys/private.key)"
    - echo "public_key_value=$(cat ./keys/public.key)"

  artifacts:
    untracked: true

And then the build step:

```yml
uild:
  stage: build

  allow_failure: false

  dependencies:
    - decryption

  script:
    - rm -rf vendor/drupal/coder
    - composer install
    - ./vendor/bin/robo ci:build
    - ls -la vendor/drupal/coder
    - echo $private_key_value
    - echo $public_key_value

  artifacts:
    name: "mycompany_build_{$CI_COMMIT_SHA}"
    expire_in: '1 week'
    paths:
      - ./build
````

Comment: Thanks for your help @ikora. But, I think my problem now is I cannot push uncommitted changes into Acquia hosting using my pipeline.